# How to get free available disk space with command?

Tags: disk-usage, disk

Show disk space with fdisk:

```
sudo fdisk -l  /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST500DM002-1BD14
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0C7DCAA1-CBD0-4A33-B210-F8D027B84A09

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048 390819839 390817792 186.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  390819840 422070271  31250432  14.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda3  422070272 423120895   1050624   513M EFI System
/dev/sda4  423120896 423153663     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5  423153664 628613119 205459456    98G Microsoft basic data
```

The free unused, available space is about:

```
total space for dev/sda - space for /dev/sda1,/dev/sda2,/dev/sda3,/dev/sda4,/dev/sda5
= 465.8G - 186.4G - 14.9G - 513M - 16M - 98G
= 166G
```

How can get the number directly with a command?
It is better not to use the method:parse all numbers from `fdisk` and combine into a calculation expression `465.8 - 186.4 - 14.9 - (513+16/1000) - 98`.

Comment: "It is better not to use the method" Why? In any case, `parted /dev/sda print free` should help, though it doesn't give you a single number. By the way, I did not know the `free` option. Thanks to Google (or DuckDuckGo), it took me a minute to learn it.

Comment: (976773168 - 628613120) * 512 bytes = 178257944576 bytes free (166 GiB) at the end of the disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sfdisk -F /dev/sdX` will print both sum of the free space and list of free space areas:

```
# sfdisk -F /dev/sde
Unpartitioned space /dev/sde: 477.77 MiB, 500973568 bytes, 978464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

 Start     End Sectors  Size
 22528   32527   10000  4.9M
 53248   69391   16144  7.9M
 71680  479231  407552  199M
479232 1023999  544768  266M
```

So if you are interested only in the sum, you can parse it from the first line:

```
# sfdisk -F /dev/sde | head -1 | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d"," -f1
 477.77 MiB
```

Note that calculating free space like this is tricky. Here I have 478 MiB of free space but that doesn't mean I can use it all, I made the partitions in a way that makes the first two free regions unusable (too small to be used) and the space at the end of the disk is not a single continuous free space. This is an exaggerated example, but I've seen worse partitioning than this :-)

If you want to get "biggest free continuous space usable for a partition" you'll need to check starts and ends, partition types etc. and that would be hard to parse from a bash output, you'll probably need to use a library (e.g. [libfdisk](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.34/libfdisk-docs/) or [libblockdev](https://github.com/storaged-project/libblockdev)) to get exact information (which means programming in C or Python).

Answer (score 0):

I like the Freddy's way most,all output contains info i'm looking for,it's no nedd to search new tool to get.let me make one more comment here for beginners as me:
Freddy's idea is right,the number is a little wrong,to get the used sector:

List all sectors used:

```
sudo fdisk -l  /dev/sda |tail -n 5
/dev/sda1       2048 390819839 390817792 186.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  390819840 422070271  31250432  14.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda3  422070272 423120895   1050624   513M EFI System
/dev/sda4  423120896 423153663     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5  423153664 628613119 205459456    98G Microsoft basic data
```

Count all used sectors in the 4th colum:

```
sudo fdisk -l  /dev/sda |tail -n 5 | awk '{count=count+$4}END{print count}'
628611072
```

It is 628611072 instead of 628613120.

```
Free sectors = total sectors - used sectors
            = 976773168 - 628611072
            = 348162096
```

One sector contains 512 bytes ,free space is :

```
(976773168 - 628611072)*512/(1024*1024*1024)
=166G
```

Thank Freddy's idea.